# Can't return Tuple, Typescript. Instead it's interpreting as an Array

Tags: typescript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to add type-safety to the return of a general function a previous dev wrote, and need help with the syntax:

```
export function to(promise:Promise<any>) {  
  return promise
    .then(data => [null, data])
    .catch(err =>  [err, null]);
 }
```

It's a pretty simple function that takes in a promise, and returns a new promise whose output type is a tuple `[Error|null, <The First Promise's Return Type>|null]`. Essentially, the first value will always be an error if one occured (else `null`) and the second will be the result of awaiting the first promise (else `null`). You can use it like:

```
const [ err, result ] = await to(/*<API Call>*/);
if (err) {
    setError(err);
    // ...
} else if (result) {
    processApiResult(result);
    // ...
}
```

I know the following's wrong (`(T|null)[]` should not be an "array of either of those types", but instead "a tuple of those types with a specific order"), but I've been banging my head against the wall & this is as close as I could get.

```
export function to<T>(promise:Promise<T>):Promise<(T|null)[]|[Error, null]> {  
  return promise
    .then(data => [null, data])
    .catch(err => [err as Error, null]);
 }
 
const [ err, result ] = await to(api.changePassword(username, password));  
// const error : string | Error | null
// const result : string | null
```

The first param should be `Error | null` (not `| string`), and the second is correct as `string | null`.

Comment: `[null, T] | [Error, null]`? But note the promise may not be rejected with an Error object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep. Thanks for clarifying that. My underlying problem ended up being TypeScript interpreting my Tuples as Arrays, and me not understanding that / knowing how to fix it. You're correct about the `Error` type, but I wanted to denote the problem without too many `any` types in the question. At this point I think I've got enough to go on. I'll return `any` in place of the error for now, but may map into a standardised error class for the app in future. 99% of the underlying errors that get returned in the app presently are actually `AxiosError` objects I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are certain that the tuples returned by `to()` will not be mutated, you can use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to type this function.

```
export function to<T>(promise:Promise<T>):Promise<readonly [Error | null, T | null]>  {  
  return promise
    .then(data => [null, data] as const)
    .catch(err => [err as Error, null] as const);
}

const [ err, result ] = await to(api.changePassword(username, password));  
// err: Error | null
// result: string | null
```

This works because `as const` will transform the type of array literals to readonly tuples.

If you don't want the tuples to be readonly for some reason, then you can also do the following:

```
export function to<T>(promise:Promise<T>):Promise<[Error | null, T | null]>  {  
  return promise
    .then(data => [null, data] as [null, T])
    .catch(err => [err as Error, null] as [Error, null]);
}

const [ err, result ] = await to(api.changePassword(username, password));  
// err: Error | null
// result: string | null
```

Either way, you just need some away of telling the compiler that the values `to()` is returning are fixed-sized tuples, not arrays.

Comment: Thanks for that Dennis. That's what I was missing; I think every approach I tried ended up with something being interpreted as an array. Both your readonly tuples approach, & Solmeas' approach of explicitly typing the return of the anonymous functions (which I didn't realise was possible at first) seems to do the trick. I'll update the title of the post as well to clarify what the underlying question was. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function to<T>(promise:Promise<T>):Promise<[Error|null,T|null]> {
    return promise
        .then((data):[null,T] => ([null, data]))
        .catch((err) =>( [err, null]));
}

async function func() {
    const [ err, result ] = await to<string>(new Promise(resolve => resolve));
    console.log(err,result)
}
```